# RoboVM - How to get notifications from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: java, media-player, listener, robovm

Title.

I want to listen when the player starts stops buffers, etc.
I am able to get the MPMoviePlaybackState, but how to use it?

I've been looking/trying for this, but no luck.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i missed the RoboVM Samples. Here's the one for MPMoviePlayerController listener

https://github.com/robovm/robovm-samples/blob/master/MoviePlayer/src/org/robovm/samples/movieplayer/viewcontrollers/MyMovieViewController.java